# The FindRoot output only with numbers

Tags: equation-solving

I have this code in Mathematica:

```
FindRoot[{Sin[x - y + 2] - x == 0, Sin[2 x - z] - 8 z == 0, Sin[z + y + z] - 2 x == 0}, {{x, 0}, {y, 0}, {z, 0}}]
```

where it's output is:

```
{x -> 0.416536, y -> 1.9869, z -> 0.0850259}
```

I want my output be like this list below (without the symbol of variables and without `->`)

```
{0.416536, 1.9869, 0.0850259}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not hard.

```
{x, y, z} /. FindRoot[{Sin[x - y + 2] - x == 0, Sin[2 x - z] - 8 z == 0, Sin[z + y + z] - 2 x == 0}, {{x, 0}, {y, 0}, {z, 0}}]
```

Comment: Thanks, Sorry for this simple question.